# PHP automatically destroys the session after login

Tags: php

```
Warning: Unknown: write failed: No space left on device (28) in Unknown on line 0
Warning: Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct () in Unknown on line 0
```

What error is this?

Comment: _" No space left on device"_... it's pretty self explanatory, I'd say...

Answer (score 2):

Your disk or partition is full

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php).

Make sure the (default) `save_path` is writable by the user your web server running as.

And check if there's enough space on your disk to write session data.